# Auto Arrange box in css or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a template and I want to know how to Auto Arrange multiple height box in css or javascript.

I already tried to change the CSS and Javascript and I've also searched on Google but I've had no luck yet.

I am giving here image for clear to know what i am looking for i am showing in this image...

[image: Format]

please check image before replay what i need

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at a library like Masonry?

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 2):

To auto-arrange elements with differing heights, there are a bunch of different libraries out there you can use. One such library is [`Masonry`](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Try out the snippet below:

```js
new Masonry(document.getElementById('container'), {
    itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

```css
.item {
    width: 25%;
}
.one {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 100px;
}
.two {
    background-color: green;
    height: 150px;
}
.three {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="item one"></div>
    <div class="item two"></div>
    <div class="item one"></div>
    <div class="item two"></div>
    <div class="item three"></div>
    <div class="item three"></div>
    <div class="item one"></div>
    <div class="item two"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at existing tools to do this like [Shuffle](http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) and [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). (Shuffle actually uses masonry.)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much detail so my answer can't have much either. It looks like you are looking for [CSS Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp). [Tables with `table-layout: fixed;`](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/) might also be of use. These layouts are called [Pinterest Layouts](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout) or Mosaic Layouts

Answer (score 0):

I have good news and bad news, followed by more good news.

The good news is that flexbox is exactly the sort of thing you could use out-of-the-box for this.  No js required -- You will set up the flow direction to be in column mode, and you will turn on wrapping.  I've provided a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cev0ug3y/

The bad news is that for this to work, you have to know the height ahead of time.  This is fine when you have a small fixed set of items to show, or if the scrolling is set up to be horizontal, but it's not so good when you want that Pinterest-like infinite scroll.

The good news is that there are a lot of people before you who've solved this using javascript -- I'd really recommend using one of those.  Refreshing the answers, I see Masonry and Shuffle have already been suggested, so I'll throw in one of my favorites (by the guy who wrote Masonry): [Isotype](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html) - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html

If you still want to roll your own, the idea is very simple:

- Initialize an array of leading edges which record the vertical height of each column of your display.  You'll be initializing this to zero.
- For each item you need to place, find the minimum leading edge who, with its neighbors, can accommodate your item.
- Set the leading edge of all participating columns to the value of the leading edge you chose plus the height of your item.

You will be using `position: absolute` to do this.  If you don't know the height of images ahead of time, you might be stuck waiting for the load to complete before placing each item.  If your items are different widths, you may have holes in your display, and there are techniques to minimize this, but it doesn't look like that's what you are doing here.  Despite all of these caveats, this should get you started, but I'd still look at third party libraries for inspiration.